# Solve the following differential equation of one independent variable

Tags: derivatives

I want to solve the following differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}(e^x-e^y)$$

I am trying to separate $x$ and $y$ in this way :
$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}(e^x-e^y)=e^x(e^{x-y}-1)$
Put $x-y=z$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{dz}{dx}$. We have
$1-\frac{dz}{dx}=e^x(e^z-1)=e^{x+z}-e^x$
$\frac{dz}{dx}=1+e^z-e^{x+z}$.
How can I separate the variable to solve the equation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Try $$e^{y+e^x}=z$$ which gives $$y=\log(z)-e^x$$ $$y'=\frac{z'}{z}-e^x$$ which simplifies the equation to $$z'=e^{2 x+e^x}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

Start by substituting $u=e^x$, whereupon the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{2x-y}-e^x$$ becomes $$u\frac{dy}{du}=u^2e^{-y}-u$$
But $u\neq0$, so we have $$e^y\frac{dy}{du}=u-e^y$$

Next, we make another substitution, let $p=e^y$, so that now the differential equation is reduced to $$\frac{dp}{du}+p=u$$
This is easily solvable by using an integrating factor, and integration by parts, giving $$p=u-1+ce^{-u}$$

Finally, putting everything back together gives the general solution $$e^y=e^x-1+ce^{-e^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}(e^x-e^y)$$  which is equivalent to write $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{e^{x-y}(e^x-e^y)}=\frac{e^{y-x}}{e^x-e^y}$$ so that $$(e^x-e^y)dx-e^{y-x}dy=0.$$
Let $M(x,y)=e^x-e^y \Rightarrow M_y=-e^y$ and $N(x,y)=-e^{y-x}\Rightarrow N_x=e^{y-x}$
which means that the D.E. not exact.

Let us seek an integrating factor $\mu$ which depends only on $x$ then $$\frac{d\mu}{\mu}=\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}dx=\frac{-e^y-e^{y-x}}{-e^{y-x}}dx=\frac{1+e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}dx=(e^x+1)dx$$  Therefore, $\ln \mu(x)= e^x+x\Rightarrow \mu(x)= e^{e^x+x}$.

Multiplying both sides of the original inequality by $\mu(x)$, we get that

$$e^{e^x+x}\cdot(e^x-e^y)dx-e^{e^x+y}dy=0.$$

Let $M_1(x,y)=e^{e^x+x}\cdot(e^x-e^y)$ and $N_1(x,y)=e^{e^x+y}$. Suppose that $\phi(x,y)=C$ is a solution of the D.E. then $\phi_y=N_1(x,y)=e^{e^x+y}$, Integrating for $y$ we get $\phi(x,y)=e^{e^x+y}+h(x)$.

Then, $\phi_x(x,y)=e^{e^{x}+x+y}+h'(x)$, on the other hand $\phi_x(x,y)=M_1(x,y)=e^{e^x+x}\cdot(e^x-e^y)$ so that $e^{e^{x}+x+y}+h'(x)=e^{e^x+x}\cdot(e^x-e^y)\Rightarrow h'(x)=e^{e^{x}+2x}-2e^{e^{x}+x+y}$. In tegrating both sides with respect to $x$, we get $$h(x)=\int{e^{e^{x}+2x}dx}-2e^y\int{e^{e^{x}+x}dx}$$

Let $u=e^x\Rightarrow du=e^xdx\Rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{u}du$, so

$$\int{e^{e^{x}+2x}dx}=\int{e^{u}udu}=ue^u-e^u=e^xe^{e^x}-e^{e^x}$$ and $$\int{e^{u}du}=e^{e^x} $$

$$\Rightarrow h(x)=e^xe^{e^x}-e^{e^x}-2e^ye^{e^x}+K$$

Hence, $$\phi(x,y)=e^{e^x+y}+e^xe^{e^x}-e^{e^x}-2e^ye^{e^x}=C$$